# Mockito - Mocked bean with setter differences between 4.11.0 and 5.8.0

Tags: java, mockito

we are migrating jdk8 to jdk17 and as part of that we are migrating mockito 4.11.0 to 5.8.0. We have a Class that we are mocking

```
        ProgramData programData = Mockito.mock(ProgramData.class);
```

which has  a bunch of getter/setters (among other things) as

```
    public final Date getBenefitsStartDate() {
        return m_benefitsStartDate;
    }

    public final void setBenefitsStartDate(Date benefitsStartDate) {
        m_benefitsStartDate = benefitsStartDate;
    }
```

there are no when() or other mockito directives for these methods.

The code under test eventually calls the setter.

in 4.11.0, the original source code is called to set the bean property.

in 5.8.0, mockito intercepts this code, and causes no action to happen, thus when we later test the value in this field it is null. Is there something new that has to happen to tell mockito not to intercept this stuff?

Comment: a silly me, this should be spy() not mock(). However apparently there is a difference in the way 4.11.0 and 5.8.0 handle using mock()

Answer (score 0):

A `Mockito.mock()` has (by default) no logic. That means a void method simply does nothing and a getter will always return the default value for the type (0 for numbers, false for booleans, empty collections for collections, null for strings and objects objects). If you want your mock object to have logic, you have to stub the methods which are called and define their return value or actions to execute.

An alternative is creating a `Mockito.spy`, which will delegate to the real methods (unless stubbed).